# Pass parameter to .bat file and git clone using ssh

Tags: git, batch-file, github, ssh, command-line

My last question was associated with resolved quesiton and closed, but it is not true, that was about https and its easy, my problem is how to pass password **using SSH**.

Question:

I'm trying to invoke a `.bat` file with parameter as password to ssh.

my `.bat` script:

```
git clone ssh://git@domain.com/project
```

I haven't found specific command git clone, like: `git clone -passphrase $passphrase$ ssh://git@domain.com/project`

Is there a command that meets my expectations or is there any other way to do it?

I work on windows. **And I can use only ssh**, the answers on stack are only for https, so don't close my question.

Comment: Use [ssh keys](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent), and not a password

Comment: this is password to ssh key :)

Comment: That's unusual to use. you will probably need to set up [`ssh-agent`](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/agent)

Comment: currently I'm using ssh-agent and I need to change it, so it isn't solution

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nepsilon/45fae11f8d173e3370c3

Comment: Your question, is about using a very specific piece of software, with or without the assistance of additional utilities, _to assist you with a task_. Those type of questions are better suited to Super User, than StackOverflow, _which assists with coding issues_.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a separate SSH key, one *not* protected by a passphrase, and used exclusively by your `.bat` script.

That way, you can revoke it easily, and that would impact only your script, not your other regular SSH key, which can remain protected by a passphrase, added to ssh-agent (even [on Windows](http://-) or [git bash for Windows](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases)), and used only during interactive session (not `.bat` unattended script execution)